# Time server for Android

Tags: clock, date-and-time

If I have an Android device that has no internet connection and I would like to use a PC as a time server. What should be the right procedures?

Is it that I should install a NTP server on my PC and then .....? How can I set the Android device to detect the time from the time server on my PC?

Thanks!

Comment: [SimpleRT](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.viper.simplert/) allows you to share your PC's internet connection with your Android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be the correct approach. As you noted, time sync needs a source -- so setting up a NTP Server on the PC will provide this source. Now you need to have some NTP client on your Android device. [Searching Google Play for "ntp"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ntp&c=apps) brings up two of them right on the first page: [ClockSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.org.amip.ClockSync) (I use this one, and am quite happy with it; still running it with the default NTP server configured -- but in your case, you will have to change this: as you can edit the time server used, this should be no issue), and [NTPSync - Time Synchronization](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ntpsync) are two examples running in the background. If you prefer something permanently visible, [Atomic Clock Wallpaper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.makarovsoftware.android.demo.atomicclockwallpaper) seems to be a candidate. Just follow the search link for more candidates :)

Comment: thanks!.... but I don't know why it didn't worked for me.... I set up the PC server as http://windowsitpro.com/windows/how-can-i-enable-network-time-protocol-ntp-server mentioned... and then in the ClockSync app, i modified the NTP setting to listen to the IP address of my PC. Both PC and the Android device are linked to the same wireless network....

Comment: plus... the app will need the Android device to be rooted?..

Comment: I cannot help you with the Windows part. As for the Android part: Yes and no. On a non-rooted device, apps can only adjust differences of 30s and higher (according to the ClockSync dev). If that's enough for you, the device does not need to be rooted -- otherwise it's a pre-condition, unfortunately. Not my design, and I cannot understand the reason for this limitation...

Comment: @Izzy The reason is that [Google refuses to allow user apps to set system time](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4581) (so ClockSync without root just helps the user set the time manually), and [there is no way to set seconds when setting the time manually](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12476) (on some devices seconds are reset to 0, but this behavior is manufacturer-specific).

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Thanks for the details! If user apps cannot do that at all, it gets understandable again. I just would not have understood if apps generally could set the time, just not that accurate :)