# Change network time (Fake)

Tags: root-access, mobile-network, date-and-time

In android you have a option to change your GPS location to a fake location.
Is it possible to "fake" the network time, so my app thinks that the actual time the fake network time is?

My phone is a Huawei G700-U10, and the Android version is 4.2.1
And I have root my device. So I can acces SuperSu.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've got root on your device, that should be possible by synchronizing time via NTP. For details, see e.g. [Time server for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46162/16575). Remaining question, though, is whether this would really override other time settings of the device (e.g. using your mobile network provider's time, which Android might use by default – see [NITZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NITZ) and [Where time information is received from the network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/43386/16575)) if they differ too much. This might be avoided by:

1. In *Settings→Date & Time*, disable automatic time adjustment
2. Install one of the apps mentioned in [Time server for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46162/16575) to take care for it
3. Setup your own "fake-time-server"
4. make that "fake-time-server" the one to be used by the app from 2.